# Primefaces dataTable filtering with datePicker range

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable and I want to filter a date column with datepicker in range selectionMode

A sample code.

```
<p:column headerText="Header" sortBy="#{recordR.date}"
          filterBy="#{recordR.date}"
          filterMatchMode="contains"
          filterFunction="#{myBean.dateFilterFunction}">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                   <p:datePicker pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" converter="javax.faces.DateTime"
                       appendTo="@(body)"
                       selectionMode="range" readonlyInput="true"
                   >
                       <p:ajax event="dateSelect" oncomplete="PF('widgetVarId').filter()" listener="#{myBean.filterByDateRange}"/>
                   </p:datePicker>
               </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{recordR.date}"/>
</p:column>
```

I don't want to filter with one calendar. I want one calendar/datepicker with date range

I use PF 7

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: The 2 base problem is that the datepicker closes in the first click and cannot  trigger the dateFunction

Comment: have you set the `widgetVar` attribute on the datatable? Also editing the question to include more information would be helpful